# React Component with Scripts That Returns Nothing

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to have a React component that only has functions in it. These functions should only run once and will run throughout the entirety of the app (these are bluetooth connection functions).

Usually I would create a class for this, but I need to access my Redux store (which can only happen in a component). The component would simply render `<></>`.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You don't need React to interact with a redux store, you know this, right? React just provides some additional bindings and works with the component lifecycle. See [Store](https://redux.js.org/api/store). You can access the store, state, and dispatch actions independent of React. If you do keep it all in React in a component, you can simply return `null` to indicate there's nothing to render.

Comment: Redux provided some hooks to access store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html) and use it in your App component. Since you can run other hooks inside, you can access the store with the [useStore](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usestore) hook and run code only once with the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook with an empty array in its dependencies.

```
function useBluetoothConnections() {
  const store = useStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    // do things once
  }, []);
}


function App() {
  useBluetoothConnections();
  return (<>
    Your app here
  </>)
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
)
```